# mmenu fixed header opens good, but closes without animation

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm working with JQuery Mobile and mmenu.js JQuery plugin. And I'm trying to set my header fixed. I've tried in two different ways:

1) With the JQuery Mobile option:

```html
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed">
```

2) With CSS:

```html
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" style="position: fixed; width: 100%;">
```

In both cases, I can open my menu correctly, with the header animation. But when I close it, close without the animation, the header just appear.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm guessing you're using CSS for animating the header?
Could you show the CSS?

Comment: @Fred Actually I don't do it the CSS, I'm using the [mmenu.js](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) library.